# transfer requests from tomcat to apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Basically I have an apache server and a tomcat server running on the same machine, when my tomcat server gets requests, based on the content type requested I would like to transfer the requests to apache server.

One approach I know is to create a URL connection to the apache server and write the data to the clients stream, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just redirect the request to apache. You could do this by adding a path as a ProxyPass.

```
# you probably have something like this in there right now
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
# this will tell apache to not proxy the /http/* path
ProxyPass /http !

# you then make an alias to your web files you want to path to
Alias /http "C:/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/htdocs">
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

of course the `/http` could be any path you want. With that setup on the Apache side you then redirect requests to a subpath.

```
@RequestMapping("/myPage")
public String viewPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(/*stuff*/) {
        // forward to the same path but with /http prepended
        return "forward:/http"+request.getRequestURI();
    }
    return "myPage";
}
```